# How to get email attachment size in python imap

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to get email attachment size in python imap

```
            # DOWNLOAD ATTACHMENTS
            for part in msg.walk():
                # this part comes from the snipped I don't understand yet... 
                if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
                    continue
                if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
                    continue
                fileName = part.get_filename()
                return HttpResponse(fileSize)
                if bool(fileName):
                    filePath = os.path.join('C:/Users/bali/attachments/', fileName)
                    if not os.path.isfile(filePath) :
                        fp = open(filePath, 'wb')
                        fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
                        fp.close()
```

Is there any function to get size of the attachment just like "get_filename()" to get the name of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Information about the attachment size is not available in the header of the MIME message (you can check this by sending an attachment to yourself and seeing the original email to see if there is any information about attachment size) but you can get the size of the attachment without "creating a file", which I consider is equivalent to "downloading the attachment".

You can do so by getting the payload of the part with attachment and then returning the length of the payload:

```
payload = part.get_payload(decode=True)
file_size = len(payload) # in bytes
```

Also, instead of checking for `part.get_filename()`, as you did in your sample code, I recommend using `is_attachment()` check on the message part OR instead of `walk()` using `iter_attachments()` to get all the message parts with attachments. You can see how the attachments are handled in this [python emails document examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have the filename, so you can use `os.path.getsize`

```
import os
os.path.getsize(part.get_filename())
```

Comment: I want the size of the attachment before download it to the folder. @brunofitas

Comment: You'll always have to download/parse the payload to count the number of bytes. There is no size label on the message, as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

You may try external lib: https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

```
from imap_tools import MailBox, A

with MailBox('imap.mail.com').login('test@mail.com', 'pwd', 'INBOX') as mailbox:
    for msg in mailbox.fetch(A(all=True)):
        print(msg.subject, msg.date)
        for att in msg.attachments:
            print(att.filename, att.size)
```